# how can i get the same object on SelectedIndexChanged event which i bind with ListBox

Tags: c#, list, events, webforms, listbox

I want the information of the object on `SelectedIndexChanged`  , i have bind with listbox.

forexample

```
listbox.bind=list of person object
```

now on each list of listitem there is a person object, i need this person object on SelectedIndexChanged event.

```
 protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

               //here is the compatibility issue 
               //how can i solve this  
                person ss = ListBox1.SelectedItem as Person;
        }
```

Comment: You can use use `list[ListBox1.SelectedIndex]`

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Forgot that `ListBox1.DataSource` is not persisted between postbacks so you'll need to save it somewhere else like the view state if its not a large object.

To save it into the view state your object has to be `Serializable`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

        persons.Add(new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Some Name" });
        persons.Add(new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Other Name" });

        ViewState["Persons"] = persons;
        ListBox1.DataSource = persons;
        ListBox1.DataTextField = "Name";
        ListBox1.DataValueField = "Id";
        ListBox1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Person> persons = (List<Person>)ViewState["Persons"];
    Person person = persons[ListBox1.SelectedIndex];
}
```

Comment: I have verified your code on selectedchange event datasouce have null value.
//DataSource is null  
List<RosterItem> persons = (List<RosterItem>)ListBox1.DataSource;